# How to Highlight PHP Method Calls in Sublime Text (textmate)

Tags: php, regex, syntax-highlighting, sublimetext3, textmate

I am using Sublime Text 3 as a PHP editor, I've been customizing the PHP.tmLanguage file to include more syntax scopes, right now I cannot figure out how to capture class method invocations.

```php
$html = new HTML("hr");
$html->output_ml("moo");
```

*output_ml* is currently declared as scope **variable.other.property.php**
I would like to add a scope to pertain to specifically to class method calls, but I am having trouble defining the regex in the tmLanguage file.

I've tried

```
<dict>
    <key>match</key>
    <string>(?i)\$[a-z_][a-z0-9_]*-&gt;([a-z_][a-z_0-9]*)\s*\(</string>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>meta.method-call.php</string>
</dict>
```

Comment: so what have you tried so far?

Comment: I editted the post to include  what I've tried

Answer (score 1):

You were pretty close, I just tweaked a few things:

```
(?i:(?!\$[a-z_][a-z0-9_]*-&gt;)([a-z_][a-z_0-9]*)\s*\()
```

First thing I did was wrap the entire expression in the "case-insensitive" modifier, just so nothing got missed. Probably not necessary, but whatever. Second, and more importantly, I took your first group that was outside of parentheses, and made them a negative lookahead. This way, they match the class name and the arrow, but don't report it - basically saying "match whatever is ahead of us as long as we exist in front of it, but don't match us."

Now, you'll have a scope that matches just the method's name.

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/oS2wK2/1)

---

Now, here's what I don't get - why you should have to do this. I maintain both a [language syntax](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Python%20Improved) and a [color scheme](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Neon%20Color%20Scheme), so I have a lot of experience with scoping in Sublime Text and TextMate. And to my knowledge, the PHP `.tmLanguage` already includes scopes for function calls. I'm not a PHP expert by any means, but I know the basics, so I made three examples of different PHP function calls:

[image: PHP function calls]

Green highlights a large variety of function calls in different languages. In the top example, `baz_quux` is scoped as `meta.function-call.object.php`, in the middle example it's `meta.function-call.static.php`, and in the bottom it's just `meta.function-call.php`. I don't understand where you're getting `variable.other.property.php` from.

However, if I take away the parentheses after the function calls above:

[image: PHP function calls, no parens]

I get the following scopes, from top down: `variable.other.property.php` (***aha!***), `constant.other.class.php`, and `constant.other.php`. If I put the parens back, and add a space or three after the end of the function name, they are still highlighted as functions, in green.

---

So, while we had some fun with regexes today, ultimately your work has already been done for you. If you're going to be doing more scope-hunting, I highly recommend the [`ScopeAlways`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/ScopeAlways) plugin, which, like its name implies, always lists the full scope of the current cursor position in the bottom bar (you can turn it off via the Command Palette if you want). If I get a request to expand my color scheme's highlighting to a new language, I just open up as much code as I can find and poke around with my mouse, looking at the different scopes, then editing my theme to correct colors as needed, or add new ones for brand-new scopes. I **then** scan through the `.tmLanguage` file (after [converting it to YAML](https://github.com/SublimeText/AAAPackageDev#convert-to-build-system)) and see if I missed anything.

Good luck with your work!